# Restricting form-based authentication in Office apps

Tags: office-js

In regards to the following message in Office 365 (and Office apps):

> To help provide additional security coverage, we are changing how
>   form-based authentication in Office applications is handled.
>   Forms-based authentication is a legacy authentication method for
>   Office resources that are not protected by Azure Active Directory
>   (AAD) or Microsoft account (MSA).

What does this mean for developers of Office apps? Does this mean we will no longer be allowed to use form based sign-in (such as email/password)? And if so, does this mean we have to switch to an OAuth based login/registration system?

Answer (score 0):

I have also asked this question on the MSDN forums - we use MS-OFBA to authenticate users, as far as I know there is no alternative. It seems Microsoft is walling off this ability to keep OneDrive a first class citizen.